# Import github project into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I want to use [this library](https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree-3d) in my android application which has been developed in android studio IDE. I downloaded the zip file from githup and extracted, then paste the unzip file in a optional folder called 'subProject' in application root.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FIZM.png).
Next I added this line to setting.gradle:

`include ':app', ':subProject:rtree-3d'`

and then change my application build.gradle to this as new dependency:

```
compile project(':subProject:rtree-3d')
```

But after cleaning and rebuilding my project I have this error:
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I also change top line to `compile fileTree(dir: 'subProject', include: ['rtree-3d'])`but there was no succeed.

How can I add this github project to my android application to use? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's a Maven project. Gradle is looking for a `build.gradle` file in there, not a pom.xml

Comment: Thanks cricket_007. This is a maven project but I imported same 2d project in android studio as a github project from project structure> dependency> maven central. Android studio find it, but rtree-3d doesn't exist.

Comment: All I said was that I don't think you can import the source code of the project into your app and expect Gradle to compile it. You'd have to clone the repo separately, build a JAR file using Maven package, then copy that into the libs folder

Comment: Thanks again @cricket_007.You're absolutely right! :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a gradle-project (but Maven (see the `pom.xml`?)), so the gradle build won't succeed, because it is looking for `build.gradle`-files.

You could build it with Maven, and add the resulting `.jar` file to your `lib`-folder of your project, in order to let gradle pick it up.

Or, even better, just add it as a dependency to your apps `build.gradle`

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.davidmoten/rtree
compile group: 'com.github.davidmoten', name: 'rtree', version: '0.8-RC10'
```

latest stable version is

```
compile group: 'com.github.davidmoten', name: 'rtree', version: '0.7.6'
```

**Edit**
Oh! my bad, actually rtree und rtree-3d istn't the same thing! So you would need to fork the rtree-3d project from github, build it with maven (clean install). Depending on your configuration gradle can access your local maven repo and pick the installed artifact from there.
But for builds on different machines you would need something like a shared Sonatype Nexus. This is something to do, so you could just copy the rtree-3d.jar from your local maven repo to the lib-folder of your gradle project and add it to your subversion/git.

Comment: Thanks @sschrass. I added this line to my build.gradle before and it worked: compile 'com.github.davidmoten:rtree:0.8-RC10'.  But it can not import rtree-3d as I need it. Also I tested your last compile line and it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, they are different. I should test it and see what's the result. Thank you @sschrass.